# How do I use np.fft.fft() to correctly identify "peak energy" and also get the associated winding frequencies?

Tags: python, numpy, signals, fft

I conceptually understand Fourier transforms. I wrote a naive algorithm to compute the transform, decompose a wave and plot it's individual components. I know it's not 'fast', and it also doesn't reconstruct the right amplitude. It was just meant to code the math behind the machinery, and it gives me this nice output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Questions**

1. How do I do something similar with `np.fft`
2. How do I recover whatever winding frequencies numpy chose under the hood?
3. How do I recover the amplitude of component waves that I find using the transform?

I've tried a few things. However, when I use `p = np.fft.fft(signal)` on the same exact wave as the above, I get really wacky plots, like this one:

```
f1 = 3
f2 = 5
start = 0
stop = 1
sample_rate = 0.005
x = np.arange(start, stop, sample_rate)
y = np.cos(f1 * 2 * np.pi * x) + np.sin(f2 * 2 * np.pi *x)
p = np.fft.fft(y)
plt.plot(np.real(p))
```

[image]

Or if I try to use `np.fft.freq()` to get the right frequencies for the horizontal axis:

```
p = np.fft.fft(y)
f = np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[-1], d=sampling_rate)
plt.plot(f, np.real(p))
```

[image]

And as a recent addition, my attempt to implement @wwii's suggestions resulted in an improvement, but the frequency powers are still off in the transform:

```
f1 = 3
f2 = 5
start = 0
stop = 4.5
sample_rate = 0.01
x = np.arange(start, stop, sample_rate)
y = np.cos(f1 * 2 * np.pi * x) + np.sin(f2 * 2 * np.pi *x)
p = np.fft.fft(y)
freqs= np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[-1], d=sampling_rate)
q = np.abs(p)

q = q[freqs > 0]
f = freqs[freqs > 0]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(q)
peaks

plt.plot(f, q)
plt.plot(freqs[peaks], q[peaks], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So again, my question is, how do I use `np.fft.fft` and `np.fft.fftfreqs` to get the same information as my naive method does? And secondly, how do I recover amplitude information from the fft (amplitude of the component waves that add up to the composite).

I've read the documentation, but it is far from helpful.

For context here is my my naive method:

```
def wind(timescale, data, w_freq):
    """
    wrap time-series data around complex plain at given winding frequency
    """
    return data * np.exp(2 * np.pi * w_freq * timescale * 1.j)


def transform(x, y, freqs):
    """ 
    Returns center of mass of each winding frequency
    """
    ft = []
    for f in freqs:
        mapped = wind(x, y, f)
        re, im = np.real(mapped).mean(), np.imag(mapped).mean()
        mag = np.sqrt(re ** 2 + im ** 2)
        ft.append(mag)
    
    return np.array(ft)

def get_waves(parts, time):
    """
    Generate sine waves based on frequency parts.
    """
    num_waves = len(parts)
    steps = len(time)
    waves = np.zeros((num_waves, steps))
    for i in range(num_waves):
        waves[i] = np.sin(parts[i] * 2 * np.pi * time)
    
    return waves
        
def decompose(time, data, freqs, threshold=None):
    """
    Decompose and return the individual components of a composite wave form.
    Plot each component wave. 
    """
    powers   = transform(time, data, freqs)
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(powers, threshold=threshold)
    
    plt.plot(freqs, powers, 'b.--', label='Center of Mass')
    plt.plot(freqs[peaks], powers[peaks], 'ro', label='Peaks')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency')
    plt.legend(), plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    
    return get_waves(freqs[peaks], time)
```

And the signal set-up I used to generate the plots:

```
# sample data plot: sin with frequencey of 3 hz. 
f1 = 3
f2 = 5
start = 0
stop = 1
sample_rate = 0.005
x = np.arange(start, stop, sample_rate)
y = np.cos(f1 * 2 * np.pi * x) + np.sin(f2 * 2 * np.pi *x)

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.show()

freqs = np.arange(0, 20, .5)
waves = decompose(x, y, freqs, threshold=0.12)

for w in waves:
    plt.plot(x, w)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What did you call `decompose` with to produce your plots?

Comment: @wwii I used frequencies of 3 and 5 to create the original wave. For the transform, I used winding frequencies of `np.arange(0, 20, 0.5)`. I went ahead and added that at the very bottom. You should be able to copy and paste the code and run it now. Oh, youll have to import `scipy.signal.find_peaks`.

Comment: `how do I recover amplitude information from the fft (amplitude of the component waves that add up to the composite).` - sounds like a maths question. Maybe check and see if it is on topic over at [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: `freqs= np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[-1], d=sampling_rate)` produces a NameError.

Comment: Funny, using the code from your third edit I get a plot similar in shape to yours but with peaks at the two frequencies specified, 3 and 5.

Comment: @wwii I must have messed up something small and perhaps didn't make the copy and paste process. At any rate, I seem to have figured it out, and your answer was very helpful. I've also started reading your book. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = 3
f2 = 5
start = 0
stop = 1
sample_rate = 0.005
x = np.arange(start, stop, sample_rate)
y = np.cos(f1 * 2 * np.pi * x) + np.sin(f2 * 2 * np.pi *x)
p = np.fft.fft(y)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[0],sample_rate)
```

The fft returns the complex values so you need the sqrt of the sum of the squares like you did for `mag` in `transform`.

- ```
  >>> p[:2]
  array([-1.42663659e-14+0.00000000e+00j, -1.77635684e-15+1.38777878e-17j])
  ```
- ```
  q = np.absolute(p)
  ```
- ```
  >>> q[:2]
  array([1.77641105e-15, 2.70861628e-14])
  ```

`fft` and `fftfreqs` give you both sides of the transform reflected around zero hz.  You can see the *negative* frequencies at the end.

```
>>> freqs[-10:]
array([-10.,  -9.,  -8.,  -7.,  -6.,  -5.,  -4.,  -3.,  -2.,  -1.])
```

You only care about the *positive* frequencies so you can filter for them and plot.

```
q = q[freqs > 0]
freqs = freqs[freqs > 0]
plt.bar(freqs,q)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: resultant plot]

---

- If there is a dc component and you want to see it your filter would be `freqs >= 0`.
- Your example has 200 data points so you get 100 (n/2) positive frequencies and the graph ranges from zero to one hundred Hz with peaks at three and five.
- [numpy.fft.rfft](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) only computes the positive frequencies. Using numpy.fft.rfftfreq to get the frequencies.

---

For me, this was/is an awesome resource - [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm) - it's on my desk at work.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation cleared up what is going on with np.fft.fft for me. Implementing your suggestions was an improvement in that here are now two normal spikes in 'energy' but they are still at the wrong frequency on the horizontal axis of the transform. Rather than the peaks resting at frequency values 3 and 5, they are at 0.144, 0.233 respectively. Perhaps this has something to do with the way I indexed things?

I will add my attempt to follow your answer as an edit.

Comment: Also, thank you for the resource. I'm more of a pure-ish math background except maybe when it comes to differential equations. I've never learned about what FFTs actually do in the real world, but now I'm interested in processing audio and visual signal for a personal project.